# Debug build of my app is working fine but not the release build signed version

Tags: java, android, android-studio

My project appears to work fine in the debug variant but crashes when I try to use the release build signed version. The same problem is occurring with some other apps I have created.

*My logcat* :

```
08-11 14:46:08.142 3809-3809/com.example.android.courtcounter W/System:     ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.example.android.courtcounter-1/lib/x86
08-11 14:46:08.342 3809-3809/com.example.android.courtcounter W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
08-11 14:46:08.919 3809-3829/com.example.android.courtcounter D/OpenGLRenderer: Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: true
[08-11 14:46:08.923  3809: 3809 D/         ]
HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xaa3dbfb0, tid 3809
[08-11 14:46:08.980  3809: 3829 D/         ]
HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xae3c7330, tid 3829
08-11 14:46:09.012 3809-3829/com.example.android.courtcounter I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
08-11 14:46:15.091 3809-3809/com.example.android.courtcounter D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
08-11 14:46:15.091 3809-3809/com.example.android.courtcounter E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.android.courtcounter, PID: 3809
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find method point2A(View) in a parent or ancestor Context for android:onClick attribute defined on view class android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.resolveMethod(AppCompatViewInflater.java:327)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:284)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

*activity_main.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.android.courtcounter.MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:padding="16dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:textColor="#616161"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
                android:padding="0dp"
                android:text="Team A"
                android:textSize="14sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/scoreA"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:padding="16dp"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
                android:text="0"
                android:textSize="56sp" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:onClick="point2A"
                android:text="+2 Points" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:onClick="point3A"
                android:text="+3 Points" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:onClick="freeThrowA"
                android:text="Free Throw" />

        </LinearLayout>
        <View
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#666666"/>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:padding="16dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:paddingBottom="0dp"
                android:textColor="#616161"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
                android:text="Team B"
                android:textSize="14sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/scoreB"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:padding="16dp"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:text="0"
                android:textSize="56sp" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:onClick="point2B"
                android:text="+2 Points" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:onClick="point3B"
                android:text="+3 Points" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:onClick="freeThrowB"
                android:text="Free Throw" />

         </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:text="Reset"
         android:layout_margin="4dp"
         android:onClick="reset"
         android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
         android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

*MainActivity.java*

```
package com.example.android.courtcounter;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
    int pointsA=0, pointsB=0;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    //Team A Methods//

    void point2A(View view)
    {
        pointsA+=2;
        displayA();
    }

    void point3A(View view)
    {
        pointsA+=3;
        displayA();
    }

    public void freeThrowA(View view)
    {
        pointsA+=1;
        displayA();
    }

    public void displayA()
    {
        TextView scoreView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.scoreA);
        scoreView.setText(String.valueOf(pointsA));
    }

    //Team B methods//

    void point2B(View view)
    {
        pointsB+=2;
        displayB();
    }

    void point3B(View view)
    {
        pointsB+=3;
        displayB();
    }

    public void freeThrowB(View view)
    {
        pointsB+=1;
        displayB();
    }

    public void displayB()
    {
        TextView scoreView = (TextView)    
        findViewById(R.id.scoreB);    
        scoreView.setText(String.valueOf(pointsB));
    }

     //Reset//

    void reset(View view)
    {
        pointsA=0;
        pointsB=0;
        displayB();
        displayA();
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you using multidex in your project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add `public` before all of your methods.

Comment: I changed the answer

Comment: I thought that since they were in the same package... mentioning no access specifier would work...